# Add percentage to number counting up jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to append a % after each number counting up from 0 - 100 and use it as a loader. I tried adding

```
$(".timer").append("%");
```

But that only adds it to the last number. Help is always appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/YWn9t/

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a `%` showing up anywhere. And post your code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could as well use css `after` pseudo class:

```
.timer:after
{
    content:'%';
}
```

and as for the javascript code, you need to append it in `updateTimer` function when you update the value:

```
function updateTimer() {
    value += increment;
    loopCount++;
    $(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals));
    $(".timer").append('%');
    ...
}
```

And ofcourse you could just add % as a sibling span element to .timer element.

Comment: That worked perfectly I completely forgot about the after pseudo class. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could just hard code a % in your HTML and then display it inline with the .timer element.

Answer (score 0):

You can append `%` when you set the HTML content inside your `updateTimer` function:

```
$(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals) + '%');
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YWn9t/897/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method each

Something like

```
$(".timer").each(function(){
    $(this).append("%");
});
```